Record Creation Test Case and Create Test Data Approach
I am quite new to Selenium and MSTEST. I have been able to run some test cases but struggling to organize things. I have a scenario where I have a test case which tests the creation of an Account Record in the system and then I have other cases where I need to perform further tests on such account records.
My approach was to create fresh account record for each test case and I am extending the same class which I used to create the Account record first. Below is the sample code:


// Web Base Class
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace TestAutomation.WebBase
{
    public class WebBaseClass
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;
        public static WebDriverWait wait;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void DriverSetUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        } 

        public void CleanUpTest()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }

    } 
    }

=========================================

//OrgBase
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using TestAutomation.WebBase;


namespace TestAutomation.OrgBase
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class OrgBaseClass : WebBaseClass
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void OrgBaseSetUp()
        {
            // Login
            ILoginManager.UILogin(driver, wait);
        }


        [TestMethod()]
        public void CreateOrg()
        {
           // Create Organisation record code
        }

    } //Organisation
} //namespace

================================================

//Validate Account Number
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using tetsAutomation.OrgBase;


namespace TestAutomation
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class Organisation : OrgBaseClass
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            //Empty. Initializing everything from base classes
        }


        [TestMethod()]
        public void ValidateAccountNumber()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Viola. All done");
        }
    } //Organisation
} //namespace

When trying to run the ValidatieAccountNumber() method in the Organisation.cs file, I am trying to create the Org/Account record by extending the OrgBaseClass. I am not sure if it the right way to do it or should I have a separate class for creating the testing data which literally will have the same code as in the OrgBaseClass and I do not want to have duplicate code.
In an ideal testing framework how would this be done ?
Also, another problem that I am facing is, when I run the above code, it is opening multiple browsers and running the automation in all of them.

Tests should be isolated from each other, so creating test data by extending test classes is not recommended. You end up coupling the tests together such that a failure in one test cascades to other tests.
The issue here is code reuse, rather than test reuse. You have non-trivial test setup logic that needs to be reused. The usual fix for this is to create additional utility classes to perform this setup, which makes it easier to write the test. You could try out the screenplay design pattern. This pairs well with the page object model pattern.
You are feeling the pain that comes with the dawning realization your automated testing framework requires as much design and analysis as the application it tests. Any design pattern you find for test automation frameworks relies heavily on the basic tenets of object oriented programming: encapsulation, data hiding, separation of concerns, inheritance, and polymorphism. Lump on top of that the SOLID design principals, dependency injection, and inversion of control.
Creating a robust and reusable automation test framework puts you solidly in the realm of Test Automation Engineer.
Unfortunately there just isn't a One True Way To Do Automated Testing. This is a very broad topic that hits almost every sub topic in computer programming. This question is akin to asking "how do I decide on an architecture for an enterprise web application?" Simple question. Very complex answer.
